# Download network folder when available

Tags: windows-8.1, nas

Is it possible to download (preferably: *one-way sync*, so also delete) a network folder, for instance `\\NAS\Music` to a local folder like `D:\Music` if available, otherwise leave it the same.

I want to listen to my music on my laptop, which is stored on the NAS, while I'm at home. But when I'm not home, I still want the most recent music library with me. Is there any way of achieving this in **Windows 8.1**?

The NAS (server, rather) is running Ubuntu Server 12.04, but I'm guessing that doesn't matter..

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You can use Bittorrent Sync to do this.

Comment: @kobaltz Would this also work while not connected to the home network?

Comment: Yup It will. (filler filler filler)

Comment: Hmm, kay, I'll check that out tomorrow then.. (@kobaltz) Post it as an answer and I will accept (tomorrow) unless a better one comes up :)

Comment: @JochemKuijpers, Journeyman Geek is correct. You do need to have an internet connection. However, since it uses P2P, the devices do not need to be on the same network.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Oh, so many ways. You can use a file synchronisation software to do this inside a lan - I favour [bvckup2](http://www.bvckup2.com/) for this (free in beta, 20 dollars when its released) these days. In my case I have a main copy of music on my desktop, and have the backup job set to run on command to a external HDD. In your case, you want it to keep the nas location (source) and the copy on the local folder synced all the time, If its not accessible, like when you're on the road it'll just silently fail.

I've also had good success with [bitorrent sync](http://www.bittorrent.com/sync) (as @kobaltz said), both on x86 and ARM (raspi) systems - create a one way share, and it'll consistantly keep these synced. I found that large filesets may lead to high CPU usage on some systems so I'd keep an eye on it initially. This is a brilliant option for mobile, constant backups, since you can set your shares anywhere, of any size, and it usually 'just works'. For the server side there's a web-ui on linux, and a desktop client, and file shares are created using a secret key anf transferred encrypted.

Comment: Thanks! Now I have at least two options, haven't got time atm but I'll let you know if or when I get this working :)